# ellipsoid of greatest volume is a sphere

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

The equation of an ellipsoid is $$f(x,y,x)=(\frac xa)^2+(\frac yb)^2+(\frac zc)^2=1$$.
Given that the volume of an ellipsoid is $$V=\frac43\pi abc$$ and the constraint $$L=a+b+c$$ L some positive constant. Show that the ellipsoid with greatest volume is a sphere.

I should use Lagrange multipliers for this question.
I tried doing $$\nabla f = \lambda\nabla V$$ which gave an anwser making no sense$$<\frac{2x}{a^2},\frac{2y}{b^2},\frac{2z}{c^2}> =\lambda <0,0,0>$$

So then I tried $$"\nabla"V=\lambda"\nabla"L$$
where $"\nabla"$ treats a as x, b as y, c as z, and got
$$4\pi/3<bc,ac,ab>=\lambda<1,1,1>$$
so $ab=ac=bc$ gives $a=b=c$ a sphere. But why am  I allowed to use $"\nabla"$ as such

Comment: The equation of the ellipsoid is irrelevant here.

Comment: Observe that both the formula for the volume and the constraint on the semi-axis lengths are symmetric in the three variables. This should immediately throw a big flag in your mind that something interesting happens when they’re equal.

Comment: @Spudnick Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are applying the [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) method to $V=V(a,b,c)$ as a function of the three parameters $a,b,c$ with the constraint $a+b+c=L$ and therefore the gradient needs to be evaluated with respect to those variables.

Answer (score 1):

Here the lagrangian reads

$$
L(a,b,c,x,y,z,\lambda,\mu) = \frac 43 \pi a b c +\lambda\left(\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^2+\left(\frac{z}{c}\right)^2-1\right)+\mu(a+b+c-L_0)
$$

The stationary conditions give

$$
\nabla L = \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 -\frac{2 \lambda  x^2}{a^3}+\mu +\frac{4 b c \pi }{3}=0 \\
 -\frac{2 \lambda  y^2}{b^3}+\mu +\frac{4 a c \pi }{3}=0 \\
 -\frac{2 \lambda  z^2}{c^3}+\mu +\frac{4 a b \pi }{3}=0 \\
 \frac{2 \lambda  x}{a^2}=0 \\
 \frac{2 \lambda  y}{b^2}=0 \\
 \frac{2 \lambda  z}{c^2}=0 \\
 \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}-1=0 \\
 a+b+c-L_0=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and solving gives

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
a & b & c & x & y & z & \lambda & \mu & V\\
 \frac{L_0}{3} & \frac{L_0}{3} & \frac{L_0}{3} & x & y & -\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{L_0^2-9 x^2-9 y^2} & 0 & -\frac{4 L_0^2
   \pi }{27} & \frac{4 L_0^3 \pi }{81} \\
 \frac{L_0}{3} & \frac{L_0}{3} & \frac{L_0}{3} & x & y & \frac{1}{3} \sqrt{L_0^2-9 x^2-9 y^2} & 0 & -\frac{4 L_0^2 \pi
   }{27} & \frac{4 L_0^3 \pi }{81} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

As can be observed the volume is maximum for $a = b = c\;$ defining a sphere. Note also the found relationship

$$
9z^2 = L_0^2-9x^2-9y^2
$$

which is a sphere.

Comment: Why clutter this up by including the equation of the sphere in the Lagrangian? It adds no relevant constraints.

Comment: @amd  Clutter? Why not include the ellipsoid restriction? Are the results unsatisfactory? As you can observe the results are completely coherent.

Comment: Yes, clutter. The equation of the ellipse provides no additional useful constraints on the half-axis lengths and adds unnecessary work.

Comment: In mathematics there is not the clutter concept. This is a subjective point of view. In mathematics there exist what is right and what is wrong.

Comment: Elegance and parsimony are important qualities in mathematical work, as is being able to recognize what is and is not relevant to a problem. The equation of the ellipsoid is irrelevant—it provides no information about the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Comment: @amd I agree with you. But also in this case, the ingenuity is relevant. by showing that you can obtain the same results,  with an immersion as global as you can do. Both  exercises are to be keep.